# Windows CE "No process is on the other end of the pipe"

Tags: windows-mobile, embedded, windows-ce

I'm trying to get debugging working for a Windows CE 5.0 application but I cannot even start the debugging process because Visual Studio throws up the error "No process is on the other end of the pipe". I can run a "Hello World" application OK but when I try to run my app which is linked against another DLL I get that error. The DLL is present in the same folder as the executable. How can I get any more information about this out of CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the program might be failing because the .dll can't be loaded.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) make sure you're specifying "/MTd" (Multi-Threaded Debug) in your build.

2) Modify your code to do an explicit "LoadLibrary()" instead of [implicit linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/253b8k2c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Check for any errors trying to load. initialize or invoke methods on the .dll.

You might also be able to accomplish the same with a try/catch (C++) or MS Structured Exception Handling (SEH, C or C++): I'm not sure.

'Hope that helps .. PSM

PS:

Windows CE 5.0 is pretty old: are you sure you can't use a newer version of Windows Mobile?  It would have both a friendlier UI, as well as a more robust development environment.  IMHO...

Comment: The LoadLibrary() suggestion worked, thanks! I tested every function until I found the offending one.

Comment: I had the same issue, it was caused by a missing library. I used this handy tool to find missing dependencies: [PEInfo](http://s-k-tools.com/index.html?m_util.html) (bottom of the page). Load your exe with File->Open and then use Info->Import to analyze dependencies.